# Set events for checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set events for checkbox to display content.

> If check="Twitter" -> display content of twitter If check="Facebook"
>   -> display content of facebook
>
> If check all (twitter + facebook) -> display content of twitter +
>   facebook
>
> Required to choose twitter or facebook.

I have handle events for checkbox but not display content for-each checkbox checked: http://jsfiddle.net/vinhnguyenle/hHnUV/

```
        var $twitter =  $('input[name=twitter]'),
            $facebook = $('input[name=facebook]');

    $twitter.click(function(e) {
        if (!!$facebook.prop('checked') == false) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $facebook.click(function(e) {
        if (!!$twitter.prop('checked') == false) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $twitter.trigger('click');
```

Please help me display content for-each checkbox checked.

Thanks,

Comment: It would help a great deal if your demo had some content to *show* once a checkbox is checked.

Comment: can not deselect twitter if you do not choose  facebook.... Please review http://jsfiddle.net/vinhnguyenle/hHnUV/

Comment: If that is what you need radio buttons would be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('div[id]').each(function(){
    if ($('input[name="' + this.id + '"]').is(':checked')){
        $(this).show();
    }
    else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});

$('input').change(function (e) {
    $('#' + this.name)[this.checked == true ? 'show' : 'hide']();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hHnUV/2/).

Comment: Thank you! But this code had error: do not uncheck checkbox if only checkbox checked.....Please help me!

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does that mean?

Comment: Please review http://jsfiddle.net/vinhnguyenle/hHnUV/ ....

can not deselect twitter if you do not choose  facebook .... Please help me!

Comment: So you're not using the code I posted, and you're asking *me* why it's not working as you'd expect? My answer is, as you might expect, *use the code I posted in my answer and demonstrated in my fiddle*. Also, in your posted demo, *there is* **still** *no content to show*

Comment: Default, checkbox checked twitter --> display content for twitter...

You can't deselect checkbox twitter if don't choose facebook ....

Comment: How can I put this? Perhaps this way: ***there is no 'twitter' content in your demo***.

Comment: I only handle events for checkbox: "Can't deselect checkbox twitter if don't choose facebook" ... I don't know display content for-each checkbox. Please help me!

Comment: It's because of the various `e.preventDefault()`s you've littered around the place. Why are they there?

Comment: Which is precisely the problem you just asked me to resolve; which means you *deliberately* created this problem. So remove the `e.preventDefault()` or don't, as you like.

Comment: I don't deliberately created this problem. This is requirement for me. Lock checkbox twitter to display content for twitter until other checkbox facebook checked to display content for both twitter and facebook. After,I can deselect checkbox twitter, but after I can't uncheck checkbox facebook, because it was lock.

Comment: with the requirement to have at least one checkbox required, it seems to make most sense to use radio buttons.  See my new answer

Comment: @Jon: unless there's a requirement to allow for *both* to be checked.

Comment: @David I agree, I added a both option in the radio button answer.

Comment: thanks, all. I'll discuss with clients for radio button replaced for checkbox. :)...Glad to be acquainted with people

Answer (score 0):

This would work, I added some div's to show facebook/twitter content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('div[id]').each(function(){
        if ($('input[name="' + this.id + '"]').is(':checked')){
            $(this).show();
         }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }

    });

    var $twitter =  $('input[name=twitter]'),
        $facebook = $('input[name=facebook]')

    $twitter.click(function(e) {
        $('#twitter').fadeToggle();
    });

    $facebook.click(function(e) {
        $('#facebook').fadeToggle();
    });

});
```

[Here is the .js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hHnUV/3/)

Comment: Please review http://jsfiddle.net/vinhnguyenle/hHnUV/...

Can not deselect twitter if you don't choose facebook...Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one event handler to monitor changes upon those inputs ...

Content added to show you the behaviour ...

Code [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bTcaQ/) `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements that twitter can't be selected if Facebook is chosen I think radio buttons with the options of: "Twitter, Facebook, Both" seems to make more sense.

JS Changes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("input:radio").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $('#Facebook, #Twitter').hide();        
        $("#"+test).fadeIn();

        if(test == "Both")
        {
            $('#Facebook, #Twitter').fadeIn();
        }
    });     
});
```

HTML Changes:

```
<input type="radio" name="social" value="Twitter" checked /> Twitter
<input type="radio" name="social" value="Facebook" /> Facebook
<input type="radio" name="social" value="Both" /> Both
<div id="Facebook" style="display:none;">Facebook Content</div>
<div id="Twitter">Twitter Content</div>
```

[JS Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/hHnUV/7/)